# Three points aligned imply an isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Let $\triangle ABC$ be a triangle and $r$ and $s$ be the angle bisectors of $\angle ABC$ and $\angle BCA$, respectively.
The points $E$ in $r$ and $D$ in $s$ are such that $AD \| BE$ and $AE \| CD$.
The lines $BD$ and $CE$ cut each other at $F$.
$I$ is the incenter of $ABC$.

Show that if $A,F,I$ are collinear, then $AB=AC$.

What I thought:

Since $AE || CD $ and $AD || BE $, so,
$\frac {FC}{CE} $ = $\frac {FI}{IA} $ = $\frac {FB}{BD} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $AE\parallel IC$ and $AD\parallel IB$, it follows that $\frac{CE}{EF}=\frac{IA}{AF}=\frac{BD}{DF}$. Hence $DE\parallel BC$.

$\angle ADE=\angle DEB=\angle CBE=\angle ABE$

Hence a circle can be circumscribed about trapezoid $ADBE$. It follows that $AB=DE$.

Similarly $AC=DE$.